# How to set base app language is Chinese Traditional in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I need to set base language to Chinese, not English.
When I change device language to Japanese, the app also show Chinese, not English.
So, I open `project.pbxproj` and change `developmentRegion` to Chinese.
And also set `Localization native development region` in info.plist to China.
I run my app, the language also show English.
Have any idea to set base language?

Answer (score 0):

#### Take Objective-C as example

---

Basically the localization form is `NSLocalizedString(<#key#>, <#comment#>)`

If you want your basic language is Chinese, then you should take the Localization key as Chinese instead of English. for example `NSLocalizedString("你好", nil)`

You will get `"Hello"` when App Language is English if you have specified some language, eg. English, in Localization file as `"你好" = "Hello"`, if not, you will get `"你好"` by default.